# How to remove leading slash before /assets/iframe.{x} for the storybook static bundle via config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

#### Intro

I have a website where i serve the storybook static of my stable branch (https://mydomain.co) and it works fine, but i also deploy previews environments on each pull requests via my CI.

The upload of each pull request is 'dynamic' meaning, that i slugify the name of the branch and end up building and uploading the storybook static to this pattern:
`https://mydomain.co/preview/{slugified-branch-name}`

#### The problem

The problem im facing is, in the `iframe.html` generated by storybook we can find this:

```
<script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/iframe.1767e7d6.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/iframe.4ea3770b.css">
```

And on my apache server this will resolve to `https://mydomain.co/assets/iframe.x`, with that in mind, the storybook instance won't be able to find it and i end up with an endless loading loop.

#### Hacky workaround

When i connect with ssh and remove the leading slash `/` in front of `assets` the storybook instance get delivered without trouble.

Today, to automate that,i have a hacky workaround in my CI. I will use sed to remove that slash after the build.

#### Via Storybook config ?

However, i would like to know if any of you had a solution to solve that problem directly with the storybook config itself and have my bundle output the src without the leading slash to end up with this in my iframe.html

```
<script type="module" crossorigin src="assets/iframe.1767e7d6.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/iframe.4ea3770b.css">
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your .storybook/main.(ts|js):

- import mergeConfig
- add the viteFinal method

```js
import { mergeConfig } from "vite";

export default {
  // ...
  async viteFinal(config, options) {
        return mergeConfig(config, {
          base: "./",
        });
  },
};
```

viteFinal is used to merge your project level vite.config.js with the vite.config.js used by storybook.

In our current situation, this piece of code will change the base path from an absolute path to a relative one when built. This should help resolve your issue and help your web server resolve the asset path correctly.

Reference: https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#base